# Better Way to Parse XML Without Knowing The Schema Beforehand

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xml-parsing

Using SQL Server 2005 I need to parse all values from XML WITHOUT knowing the element names beforehand.

Here is what I have:

```
declare @xml xml

--REMEMBER THIS XML COULD CONTAIN ANYTHING. THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
set @xml = '
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>1</id>
  <name>asdf</name>
  <siteaddress1>asdf</siteaddress1>
  <siteaddress2>asdf</siteaddress2>
  <sitecity>asdf</sitecity>
  <sitestateid>4</sitestateid>
  <sitezip>333333</sitezip>
  <phone>asdfsadf</phone>
  <epaid>34343</epaid>
</row>'

declare @rows int
declare @i int
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @i = 0
set @rows = (SELECT Tbl.Col.value('count(*)', 'int') FROM @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col))
set @sql = ''

while (@i <= @rows)
begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    set @sql = @sql + 'select Tbl.Col.value(''*[' + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + ']'', ''varchar(max)'') 
                       FROM @x.nodes(''//row'') Tbl(Col)
                       union '
end

set @sql = substring(@sql,0,len(@sql)-5)

exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@x xml', @x = @xml;
```

This works but it's ugly and not set based. There has to be a better way.

EDIT. In my case the schema will always be

```
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
...
...
</row>
```

Comment: XML and SQL (especially sql server 2005) don't work well together. Plus, given that the XML could be *anything*, what if you have a schema like <a><b><c></c><d></d></b><e></e></a>? Is your schema at least somewhat static??

Comment: @N West. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @xml XML

set @xml = '
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>1</id>
  <name>asdf</name>
  <siteaddress1>asdf</siteaddress1>
  <siteaddress2>asdf</siteaddress2>
  <sitecity>asdf</sitecity>
  <sitestateid>4</sitestateid>
  <sitezip>333333</sitezip>
  <phone>asdfsadf</phone>
  <epaid>34343</epaid>
</row>'

select r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as 'elementName',
    r.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS 'value'
FROM
    @xml.nodes('//row/*') AS records(r)
```

If you just want the distinct element names you just have to do:

```
select distinct r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as t FROM
    @xml.nodes('//row/*') AS records(r)
```

Comment: This works for the elements, how to extract the Attribute values?